# Do I require JavaScript for printing purpose

Tags: java, javascript, mysql, jsp, servlets

This is scenario based problem. I have developed an application in JSP - Servlet environment, which prints few things on print roll paper attach to computer through USB. The scene is when I press `print` button on JSP. It goes to a appropriate Servlet class. From there it fetches data from database. I am using MySQL. And finally fetched data is sent as parameters to print purpose class which takes string buffer as parameter. Application is running fine on when tested on localhost. But my senior is again and again asking me to use JavaScript for this purpose. He is saying this code will not be run on client side with printer attach to client PC. It can only run on server side. What should I do?

Comment: Could you maybe show what you have tried so far?

Comment: It is actually a large code .. not very well formatted. should I paste it along with question

Comment: You don't need to show anything. Torean is just not understanding it either. Hint: your approach works only when both server and client run at physically the same machine. This is however usually not true on the Internet.

Comment: @BalusC can you provide some more hints on how can I modify my approach

Answer (score 1):

Listen to your senior programmer, java code runs on server side, **you must print via javascript** if you want same behaviour in production.

If you have network, connect via ip instead of localhost from another computer to simulate client-server sides and you will see by yourself whats going on

Comment: can you provide some hints on how to resolve this problem.. How to use javascript to access database and then accessing java print purpose class..

Comment: Accessing database is server side! You have to use java for that, just send the retrieved data via String (or JSon if complex objects) and translate java code that prints into javascript. For furter info please post some code!!